# Simple number format from api

Tags: php, number-formatting

I'm pulling one number from the api. The output when I call the value directly is

```
1597188700000000
```

Desired output on the page is

```
15, 971, 887
```

What I'm trying is

```
function formatMoney($number, $fractional=false) { 
    if ($fractional) { 
        $number = sprintf('%.2f', $number); 
    } 
    while (true) { 
       $replaced = preg_replace('/(-?\d+)(\d\d\d)/', '$1,$2', $number); 
       if ($replaced != $number) { 
          $number = $replaced; 
       } else { 
          break; 
       } 
    } 
    return $number; 
}
```

Then `formatMoney($totala)` ( $totala is the amount from api ) and I see on the page

```
1,597,188,700,000,000
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What input do you hand over to that function? So what are `$number` and `$fractional`?

Comment: None.. I've took this from php.net manual.

Comment: This one: http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php#98783

Comment: You have to specify an argument when you call that function, regardless of where that function comes from.

Comment: Tried myself, that function works fine for me.

Comment: I have the impression that you are either trying to use that function for something it is not meant for or that you did not understand what the function actually does.

Comment: Why should an inputvalue of `1597188700000000` result in an output of `15, 971, 887`?

Comment: Most probably I don't understand the function correctly. Well because I know that expected value is 15 millions+ ..

Comment: Add another zero to the end and you will get the desired result, otherwise the output will be 1, 597, 188....

Comment: Sorry, but `1597188700000000` certainly is more than 15 millions...

Comment: How do you know if the zeros belong to the number or if they should be stripped off? Should zeros always be stripped off?

Comment: Correct on first sign it is more. But divine by 100000000 do the trick. Sorry for took your time guys ... seems like my logic is completely wrong.

Comment: Certainly dividing some number by another number will result in a smaller number. I don't see what that has to do with the function presented here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Money format is from right to left in 3 digit groups.

The question is what your number should be:
1597188700000000 or 15971887?

You need to be sure what is the unit and then change it to desired format. If you want "15, 971, 887" from 1597188700000000.
You need to get every number from api and do: 1597188700000000/100000000 and then format it.

I think the question is senseless though and you haven't think about what are you doing.

Comment: Actually this is working when I do like `formatMoney($totala/100000000, true);`

Comment: Yes but 1597188700000000 != 15971887.

If you go to the shop and the price is 1000$, then it's not 1$. You have to know what is the unit.

If your number need to be set in 16 places (I'm guessing that is a problem):
1597188700000000

You should save it like this:
000000001597188.

It will be valid when your number will be like:

000000159718800, so 159718800.

Comment: If you have access to source data - you can try to save value 1.

It should save 000000000000001 and not 100000000000000

Comment: I can't control what I receive from api. I just know that I need to show on page `15, 971, 887` from received number which is `1597188700000000` i.e. exactly divided by 100000000

Comment: Can you then validate value with other record, that it should be divided by 100000000 too? When your answer is YES: You should divide it every time.
If it's NO: You have no chances to guess what your number is. Possible solution is to change the way that number are saving to source database, or revalidate your API connector, and check that you are not formating it wrong.

Comment: BEFORE it hits function from your question.

Comment: I should divided each time. I'm not sure in this way if @Peter's answer will help me. Sure it's gave me desired output but is it equal to  `/100000000`

Comment: Just make sure what is the unit. You should be cautious with dividing, because it is for me just a random number. Just revalidate what I wrote above or contact API supplier to know for sure what it is.

Comment: With below answer:
Make sure if "echo number_format(rtrim(10000, '0'), 0, ',', '.');"
When input is 10000 with result "1", is fine. I can bet it is not :)

Comment: You can test variable type with:
echo get_type($number);

BEFORE it hits the function. And write the output.

Answer (score 1):

The following will format your number, separating the thousands with a `,` and stripping all zeros from the right part of the number.

```
$formattedNumber = number_format(rtrim($number, '0'), 0, ',', '.');
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: This doesn't work. It returns `Wrong parameter count for number_format()`. First one before edit was worked.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: I like this approach ( even if I'm not sure if is correct ) because is just one line and I can remove the function. Thanks.